# Add sample image in template header in whatsapp cloud API

Tags: node.js, api, cloud, whatsapp

I am doing a project using WhatsApp cloud API. I need to create a template with a media header. I have created a template with a media header without a sample image and it gets rejected. So I want to create a template with a sample image in Node.js.

Template with a media header:

[image: Template with a media header]

Add sample image for a template:

[image: Add sample image for a template]

```
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{whatsapp-business-account-ID}/message_templates
  ?name={template-name}
  &language=en_US
  &category=TRANSACTIONAL,
  &components=[{
       type:BODY, 
       text:{message-text}
     }, 
     {
       type:HEADER, 
       format:IMAGE, 
       example:{header_handle:[{uploaded-image-file-url}]}
     }],
  &access_token={system-user-access-token}"
```

I want to add a sample image using Node.js (not manually like the second picture).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi Shanthini, were you able to find solution for your problemo

Comment: No. I haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

header_handle requires a encrypted file upload provided by facebook.

This can be done by calling 2 apis.

**First**,
We have to create a session for the file to be uploaded.
For creating session refer [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/uploads/)

After creating session, we will get session id to upload the original file to it.Response will look something like this:

> {"id":"upload:MTphdHRhY2htZW50Ojlk2mJiZxUwLWV6MDUtNDIwMy05yTA3LWQ4ZDPmZGFkNTM0NT8=?sig=ARZqkGCA_uQMxC8nHKI"}

**Second**,We have to upload the file to
[https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{above_id}](https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/%7Babove_id%7D)

This will give a response something similar to

> {"h":"2:c2FtcGxlLm1wNA==:image/jpeg:GKAj0gAUCZmJ1voFADip2iIAAAAAbugbAAAA:e:1472075513:ARZ_3ybzrQqEaluMUdI"}

**Finally,**

> {header_handle:["2:c2FtcGxlLm1wNA==:image/jpeg:GKAj0gAUCZmJ1voFADip2iIAAAAAbugbAAAA:e:1472075513:ARZ_3ybzrQqEaluMUdI"]}

Should be added during the request to create template.

It worked for me.

See [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/) for better understanding on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how to send an image file to the API. Can you plz share some examples?

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853167/add-a-template-sample-image-to-whatsapp-cloud-api?noredirect=1&lq=1) There are examples here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer Provided by Aravindh is correct, you can follow [This document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/) from Meta to upload the Image you want.

Just make sure you use a supported type by WhatsApp API ( For [WhatsApp Business Platform Cloud API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#supported-media-types) ,  For [WhatsApp Business Platform On-Premises API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/reference/media#supported-files) ) and the upload end point ([file-type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/#step-1--create-a-session) — The file's MIME type. Valid values are: image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, and video/mp4
)

Double Check if you are following exacly the types supported, for example in case of png, you need to set "file_type" to "image/png" no just "png" when [creating the upload session.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/uploads/#parameters)

I have tested it and it works for me.

Hope this helps