# Add a Template sample image to WhatsApp Cloud API

Tags: c#, api, facebook-graph-api, cloud, whatsapp

Good day

I am trying to create a template in `C#` with a media header using the WhatsApp cloud API as described here: [Resumable Upload API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload/).
Now whenever I create the template an error is returned: **File type not supported**.

I have searched online for examples for other developers who experience the same but none found that resolved my issue.
I have followed the suggestions/solutions in these two posts, but still bo luck:

- [Add sample image in template header in whatsapp cloud API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72444051/add-sample-image-in-template-header-in-whatsapp-cloud-api)
- [Facebook graph api create whatsapp template image with resumable upload api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736440/facebook-graph-api-create-whatsapp-template-image-with-resumable-upload-api/73749941)

**My Steps:**

1. I create a session successfully.
2. I use the sessionId returned to upload the media, also without issue.
3. I then try to create the template with the handle returned (in step 2). This step returns the error **File Type Not Supported**.

Code:

### Create session

```
// Create the session
var sessionId = "";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{appId}/uploads"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");

        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"file_length\":\"16384\",\"file_type\":\"image/png\",\"file_name\":\"test.png\"}");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionResponse>(responseContent);
        sessionId = result.id;
    }
}
```

### Upload media

```
var handle = "";
var dataBinary =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\IMAGES\test.png");
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{sessionId}"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "OAuth " + _accessToken);
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("file_offset", "0");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        multipartContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(dataBinary));
        request.Content = multipartContent;

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaUploadSessionResponse>(responseContent);
        handle = result.h;
    }
}
```

### Create template

jsonData: (complete handle not added in this example)

```
{
    "name":"template_media",
    "components":[
       {
          "type":"HEADER",
          "format":"IMAGE",
          "example":{
             "header_handle":[
                "4:::ARaVEoRalHjf9hIFnYJb2O9I6BJeHNoonwkB...."
             ]
          }
       },
       {
          "type":"BODY",
          "text":"Please find media attached as requested."
       }
    ],
    "language":"en_US",
    "category":"TRANSACTIONAL"
 }
```

Request:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{_businessAccountID}/message_templates"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);

        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonData);
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

### Error Returned (*File Type Not Supported*):

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Invalid parameter",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2388084,
        "is_transient": false,
        "error_user_title": "File Type Not Supported",
        "error_user_msg": "The type of file is not supported.",
        "fbtrace_id": "AZalksSZjALNaBLXiiJzgZw"
    }
}
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: first, try this flow in postman, after the success you can try it in your code. follow the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73459394/8987128). and this is [postman collection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/postman/?translation) for quick test.

Comment: Thank you turivishal, I tried that as well but no luck.

Comment: you are probably doing something wrong or missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, hope this helps others with the same issue.

Instead of adding the "Content-Type" headers to the request I added them on **request.Content**, for example: `request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");`

I also changed the `MultipartFormDataContent` to a `ByteArrayContent` with the content header `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

See below for a full code example that worked for me.

### Create the session

```
var sessionId = "";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{appId}/uploads"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);
        
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"file_length\":\"16384\",\"file_type\":\"image/png\",\"file_name\":\"test.png\"}");
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return null;

        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SessionResponse>(responseContent);
        sessionId = result.id;
    }
}
```

### Upload media

```
var handle = "";
var dataBinary =  System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\IMAGES\test.png");
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{sessionId}"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "OAuth " + _accessToken);
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("file_offset", "0");

       request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(dataBinary);
       request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return null;

        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MediaUploadSessionResponse>(responseContent);
        handle = result.h;
    }
}
```

### Create template

jsonData: (complete handle not added in this example)

```
{
    "name":"template_media",
    "components":[
       {
          "type":"HEADER",
          "format":"IMAGE",
          "example":{
             "header_handle":[
                "4:::ARaVEoRalHjf9hIFnYJb2O9I6BJeHNoonwkB...."
             ]
          }
       },
       {
          "type":"BODY",
          "text":"Please find media attached as requested."
       }
    ],
    "language":"en_US",
    "category":"TRANSACTIONAL"
 }
```

Request

```
var responseContent = string.empty;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), $"https://graph.facebook.com/v14.0/{_businessAccountID}/message_templates"))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + _accessToken);

        request.Content = new StringContent(jsonData);
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return null;

        responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual HTTPs request you are sending for each step? (e.g. postman, pcap, etc.)