# Creating Media Templates and Sending Media Templates Whatsapp Cloud API

Tags: whatsapp

Every time I create a media template it gets instant reject even though I put an example.. anyone knows why? Ive been doing it manually from the whatsapp template platform and checked the 'network' under inspect and I can see meta sends an API with a different link they send a link from this address - >

https://scontent.whatsapp.net/v/t61.29466-34/158807847_652000016644927_1195425501539140954_n.jpg?ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=57045b&_nc_ohc=jjdNLduxuZUAX_kDzVR&_nc_ht=scontent.whatsapp.net&edm=AH51TzQEAAAA&oh=01_AVzh5kOlodJM9ZgIeTI-dv6NBpesRplXwUF-FkB5GMsoHg&oe=63349507

Ive been trying to upload media through API and I get a different URL - >

https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/whatsapp_business/attachments/?mid=605081004677112&ext=1664271173&hash=ATsf5Tr0brZWlQl2HmUzdZ8ZbNYgMUECGSn1wUgV89HRJg

When I send the template with the #2 URL I get this error ->
code': 131053, 'title': 'Downloading media from weblink failed with http code 500

And when I send the template with the #1 URL I get the same error but with error code 403.

So what is the right way to upload a media template without getting rejected?
And what is the right way to send that template with an image?
How do you upload an image to whatsapp platform and get back a url of scotent? and not lookaside?

I do get back an "id" of the template so everything seems to work except the media part.

Ive been following the documentations and followed every step I have no idea what is not working well..

Thank you in advance,
Jonathan.

Comment: here is the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73853167/add-a-template-sample-image-to-whatsapp-cloud-api).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out my self, so if any one is getting this problem here is how you should solve it:

First of all templates getting rejected because the example link, its not working.

1. We will make it work by making a media upload get its ID
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media

2. Grab the media details from the get method or save it from your app
3. Create an upload session and get the id of the upload session
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload
4. Initiate Upload with the upload session id as referenced in and save the id
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/upload
5. Upload a new template, on the example part put the hashed id it will get approved as they can get the image
6. When sending the template to clients instead of using link as key in the image part use id as key and as the value put the upload id from step 1